# ADFS Claims Rule Language

Tags: adfs, claims

I have an Intranet based ADFS website that uses a standard logon page.

Is it possible to change this in the claims language so that it will automatically accept the user based on the authenticated user currently logged on.

I have looked at using the claim rules language but so far all I have got is

```
c:[Type != ""] => issue (claim = c);
```

which I got from a video.

I am assuming that I can add a claim to ADFS which can be tested for the website and grant or deny access.

Any help on the claim, or the claims language would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can.

In the claims-rules wizard, use the middle tab - "Issuance Authorisation Rules".

Refer : [Create a Rule to Permit or Deny Users Based on an Incoming Claim](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee913594(v=ws.11).aspx).